# 「このスクリプトの OAuth ID が無効です」が出るようになった

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps for Worksの環境でこれまで何ヶ月も支障なく動作していたGoogle Apps Scriptプログラムが、起動すると「このスクリプトの OAuth ID が無効です」というエラーで動かなくなりました。
手作業で起動すると、2回目は動作するのですが、その後、またランダムに同じエラーで止まります。

典型的な例は、下記のようなものです。

1. スプレッドシートを作成する
2. 新規にGoogle Appsスクリプトを作成し、次の一行のスクリプトを入力する

   ```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(スプレッドシートのID);
   ```
3. 実行する
4. 一連のオーソライズのやりとりの後に、「このスクリプトの OAuth ID が無効です」というエラーメッセージが出力されて止まります。下記スクリーンショットご参照。

ユーザーアカウントを変えても、他のドメインで試しても同じ結果になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

管理コンソール ▶ セキュリティ ▶ API リファレンス ▶ API アクセスを有効にするにチェックしても効果はありませんでした。

数日前、数十あるGASプログラムで、この障害が一斉に発生しました。

オンラインでこれらのGASプログラムを呼び出しているWebアプリケーションが止まってしまうので、かなり致命的です。

なにか対策方法があればご教授下さい。

---

解決したようです。
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4694#c17

Comment: 特に不都合がない様であれば、GAS issuesのURLも質問に記載されてみては如何でしょうか？将来的にこのページを見た人への情報共有や解決策の提示につながるかもしれません。(GAS issuesに同じ人物と思われる方を見かけたもので、勘違いでしたらすみません。)

Comment: はい、下記に投稿したのも私です。
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=4694

同様の回答が投稿されています。

Comment: その回答をしたのが私だからですね。issueが上がっていた為、Google側の問題も考えましたが、JSDoc書いてみたら解決したので。もしこの方法で解決しなかった場合は、詳細を質問やコメントで教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

認証方法については下記のページにまとまっているようです。
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

### [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), [Document service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/), or [Forms service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Sheets, Docs, and Formsについては`.gs`に`@OnlyCurrentDoc`(または`@NotOnlyCurrentDoc`)のJSDoc(file-level comment)が必要です。
スクリプトファイルの先頭に下記のJSDocを記述してください。

**JSDoc:**

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

### 2013/07以前に作られたスクリプト

`[ファイル] ▶ [承認手続きをアップグレード...]`から承認手続きを改めて行う必要があります。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#upgrading_authorization_experience

**余談:**
時期的(2015/01)に、GoogleのOAuth 1.0廃止が関係してるのかもしれません。

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#shutdown-timetable

**2015/01/21 追記:**
Google内部に問題が報告されたとのことで、現状Google側の問題である可能性が高そうです。

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4694#c13

Comment: ご回答たいへん、ありがとうございます。  
確かに、この方法でSpreadsheetに組み込まれたGASではエラーが出なくなります。  
しかし、実は、私が直面している問題は、スタンドアローンのGASプログラムで、この方法では回避できませんでした。  
@OnlyCurrentDocを指定すると、スタンドアローンのGASプログラムは、他のドキュメントにアクセスすることができなくなり、何もできなくなってしまうのです。

Comment: 回答に記載したリンク先に書かれている`@NotOnlyCurrentDoc`を付けて実行しても駄目でしょうか？

Comment: `@NotOnlyCurrentDoc`を付けて試してみたところ、初回実行ではOAuthのエラーが出ますが、もう一度実行するとエラーが出ませんでした。

Comment: 再度確認したところ、2回実行すると成功すると言うのはJSDocの有無に関わらず、のようでした。すみません。また、もし現象の再現手順(最小のコード)があれば質問に追記をお願いします。私が試していたのは`DriveApp.searchFiles()`です。